# Responsive website doesn't scroll smoothly on iPhone

Tags: iphone, debugging, responsive-design

I am having troubles with scrolling on my website on an iPhone.

What I mean by that is that normally, when you start scrolling and then release the display, the site will keep scrolling for a bit on an iPhone. But with this site, it doesn't. As soon as you remove your finger from the display, it will stop scrolling. It is as if the scrolling is sticky.

I really have no idea where I should even begin to look to debug the problem, which is why I am not posting the code (I'd have to post the complete website).
The issue is also not showing up on my Nexus 5. I have had the issue on two different iPhone 5.

I am basically looking for points to start to debug the problem right now.

Comment: I too have had this problem, but for me the problem was that the boxes for the buttons on my page went beyond the screen which caused the iphone to have sticky movement. It was quite weird. Also another time it was because I had too many scripts and too many images in the page, causing a lag on iphone.

Comment: Hm I don't really have boxes for buttons, but I'll check whether the content is too wide for the screen. 
We do have a lot of scripts on the page, but it's not like this is the only one that has that, and all other pages load and scroll just fine.

Comment: I found -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; and when I add it to html, body {} it works except it messes up the site...

Comment: In what way does it alter the site? Like its layout?

Comment: Ok so here's a basic layout of the site : http://s30.postimg.org/coc8xmo69/first.png

When you first go to the site on, say, an iPad, it looks all fine. Once you scroll down and then back up, everything is basically.. all over the place. As in, say, parts or all of panel B, C and D are inside panel A, somewhere around the border or in the middle.
In panel A there are also two buttons which, after scrolling back up, show up twice (after scrolling down and back up again they sometimes appear three times), and there's a navbar atop that won't show up at all after scrolling. It just disappears...

Comment: It doesn't do this on the desktop site, only on the iPad (and I'd assume iPhone but I don't have an iPhone around so I couldn't really check).

Comment: Ok so I found out that html,body {height: 100%} kinda breaks the scrolling. It also breaks if I use jQuery to make html,body the height of the window.
There's a main banner that has to be 100% high but only on the homepage, so I now use jQuery to set the height of that element to the window height, which works fine on the iPad but not on the iPhone.

Gonna dig some more.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this script on the master page means if you have a Common layout page :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i);
    if (agentID) {       
       $('body').css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');
    }
});
```